# Who is stuck inside the jar in Episode 5 of Loki?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, loki-2021

In Episode 5 of Loki,

> we see a character stuck inside the Jar tagged "T365" trying to reach out for a Mjolnir for a brief second. Who is this character?

> [image]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### Throg

Throg can be a few things but there is the main 616 version where it is actually Thor who has been turned into a frog. The label on the jar here is a reference to this version as the first appearance was in *Thor* Issue 365.

[image: Thor as a frog picks up Mjolnir and turns into Throg]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Of interest is that apparently there was a scene shot, that was ultimately cut, back in the Time Theater where we see Throg pummelling Loki.

> **ENTERTAINMENT WEEKLY: Let's start with Frog Thor. Episode 4 writer Eric Martin mentioned on Twitter that you guys actually filmed a scene with Loki and Frog Thor in the time theatre for the premiere. What actually happened in the scene?**
>
> **MICHAEL WALDRON:** There was a version alongside the D.B. Cooper sequence of kind of Loki's Greatest Hits. There was another greatest hit of the time that Thor was turned into a frog and that's in this case left to the imagination. But yeah, we did almost get there in there. But I am glad that we see that Frog Thor.
>
> <sub>[Entertainment Weekly, *Loki* boss on Frog Thor, Loki and Sylvie's bond, and why Marvel isn't like the TVA](https://ew.com/tv/loki-finale-preview-michael-waldron/)</sub>

> **@MrEricMartin:** Comic fans will notice the Frog of Thunder in that jar. We actually shot a scene for the Time Theater in Ep 1 of Loki getting pummeled by Frog Thor, but had to cut it to keep things moving. It’s too bad, because Tom was funny as hell. #LokiMidnightTheater
>
> <sub>[Twitter, @MrEricMartin, 2021/07/08 5:10](https://twitter.com/MrEricMartin/status/1412987552324145152)</sub>

Comment: Where's Jason Baker when you need him :-(

Comment: @Randal'Thor It's [Bason Schmaker](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7382/21267), get it right ;-)